# PHP Pear Mail not working

Tags: php, email, pear

I have been able to use the PEAR package code on a godaddy server that has PEAR installed and everything works as intended, however when I try to execute the code on my local machine I receive no emails and no error messages that gives me any indication of what is going wrong.

From what I have gathered from numerous sources on the web is that once I have installed PEAR I need to setup the `include_path` in the "php.ini"

Also in the php.ini file I have added

```
[mail function]
; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/smtp
SMTP = localhost
; http://php.net/smtp-port
smtp_port = 25

; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/sendmail-from
sendmail_from = myemail@gmail.com ****[Hidding real email address]****
```

PHP installation as followed:

- php installation path `c:\php`
- pear installation path `c:\php\pear`
- php.ini `include_path = ".;c:\php\pear"`
- Pear packages `c:\php\pear` - *gathered from `pear list`*

  - mail
  - mail_Mime
  - Net_SMTP
  - Net_Socket
  - PEAR

Any help on this matter will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you set `error_reporting` to `E_ALL` and `display_errors` to `On` in your `php.ini` file? Also, do you have an SMTP server running on your machine?

Comment: Are you on Windows on your dev machine? If so do you have an SMTP server running?

Comment: Did you perform the install as Administrator?

Comment: I solved this problem recently on a Windows 7 machine.  I had to 'borrow' the mail servers from my ISP (didn't want to install an SMTP mail server on my Windows 7 box).  In my Win7 box's c:/xampp/sendmail/sendmail.ini file, with my ISP being Comcast, I'm 'borrowing' their mail servers *AND* I do have a valid Comcast account, I set smtp_server=smtp.comcast.net, and smtp_port=587, and 
auth_username=myComcastAccountUsername@comcast.net and auth_password=myComcastAccountPassword and that allows me to use my ISP's mail servers for localhost development of emailing code.

Comment: I had not installed a SMTP mail server on my machine, I just assumed that php would have come pre-packaged with one, my bad! I will mark this as resolved now as this was the final step to get it working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to install an SMTP mail server on my machine. You can install one on a windows machine by following the answer in this question. [Need a lightweight, free, windows SMTP server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30076/need-a-lightweight-free-windows-smtp-server)